# I am a little bit confused about creating kinda a loop

Tags: python

I'am at the beginning of my road into python, this is my first creation in python and I have a little bit of a problem, I've created a basic calculator, it works kinda good, but my question is how can I make the calculator ask again for num1 and operator after I run it, I mean, I run it, it works, but after the calculation is done, I have to rerun it in order to ask for num1 and op. How can I make it ask again for num1 and op when you press a key after a calculation is done.
This is my first time asking here and if my question is too basic, I'm sorry.

```
import math
#creating our variables
num1 = float(input("Enter the first number: "))
op = input("Enter the operator: ")

#creating the calculator for simple calculations
if op == "+":
    num2 = float(input("Enter the second number: "))
    print(num1 + num2)
elif op == "-":
    num2 = float(input("Enter the second number: "))
    print(num1 - num2)
elif op == "*":
    num2 = float(input("Enter the second number: "))
    print(num1 * num2)
elif op == "/":
    num2 = float(input("Enter the second number: "))
    print(num1 / num2)

#creating the advanced calculations
elif op == "square":
    print(num1**2)
elif op == "cube":
    print(num1**3)
elif op == "square root":
    print(math.sqrt(num1))
elif op == "square number":
    num2 = float(input("Enter the second number: "))
    print(num1**num2)
elif op == "cube root":
    print(num1**(1/3))
else:
    print("Error, please enter a valid operator")
```

Comment: As you already said yourself, [you need a loop](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_while_loop.htm).

Comment: You will need an infinite loop and an exist condition.  `while [ True ]:   <Your code>  ; Exit condition like ask user if he wants to continue and if we says yes  ; break`

Comment: You say you are new to python.  Is it your first programming language?  Nearly all languages have the concept of a loop.  This is what you need.

Comment: What exactly does “creating **kinda** a loop” mean?

Comment: @PrashanthMariswamy - OP requires a `while` loop, not in infinite loop.  Very different things.

Comment: Thank your for all of your suggestions, yes this is my first programming language, I knew I assumed I need a loop, but didn't know how to write it properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run the calculator within a `while` loop to rerun it continuously.

The simplest way is:

```
while True:
    #calculator code
```

Or you can have a condition that ends the program:

```
keep_running = True

while keep_running:
    #calculator code

    if input('Keep Computing? (yes/no) ').lower() == 'no':
        keep_running = False
```

This is just a simple example but hopefully it breaks down the concept for you.